# Reversing a stack recursively

Tags: c++

Im trying to reverse a stack, by simply putting it into another stack from the top, so that it could be reversed.
Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

stack<char> Reverse(stack<char> &st) {
  stack<char> sk;
  if (st.empty()) return sk;
  sk.push(st.top());
  st.pop();
  Reverse(st);
}
int main() {
  stack<char> st;
  st.push('a');
  st.push('b');
  st.push('c');
  st.push('d');
  stack<char> sk = Reverse(st);
}
```

Please help me find the error.

Comment: Missing return for one path, and `sk` is "unused".

Comment: What will `Reverse` return when `st.empty()` is false? And what happens with the return value of `Reverse(st);` in the recursive call?

Comment: OT: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) Habits, good and bad, tend to stick. So even if you say "it's just for a small example so it's no big deal", if that example have bad habits you will get used to those bad habits. Better use good habits everywhere, even for small examples.

Comment: You should tell us what the error is / how it demonstrates itsefl, we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
std::stack<char> Reverse(std::stack<char> &st, std::stack<char>&& res = {}) {
  if (st.empty()) return std::move(res);
  res.push(st.top());
  st.pop();
  return Reverse(st, std::move(res));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b65f715f98b08030)